# Devolver una lista de un objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente modelo con un método para recuperar una lista de datos del mismo modelo.

```
public class Totem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Dato1{ get; set; }
    public string Dato2 { get; set; }
    public string Dato3 { get; set; }

    public List<Totem> GetTotem()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnString))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;

                SQL += "SELECT id, dato1, dato2, dato3";
                SQL += " FROM";
                SQL += " mitabla";

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "mitabla");
                    conn.Close();

                    this.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["suc"].ToString());
                    this.Dato1= dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato1"].ToString();
                    this.Dato2 = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato2"].ToString();
                    this.Dato3 = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato3"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Al llamar al metodo GetTotem desde mi controlador debería traerme una lista de todos los datos que estoy solicitando (todos los datos de la tabla de solo esos 4 campos) pero nbo se como retornar esa lista...

Quien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Muestra el código de tu Controller; en la vista tienes que llamar a ese modelo de datos (Totem) para mostrar los valores. @model Lugar.Totem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes ningún **return** en esa función debes **inicializar** una lista del mismo tipo que la función agregar elementos y retornarla al salir de la función, yo preferiría definir esa clase **Totem** y sus propiedades por un lado y la lista **GetTotem()** en otra clase lo digo porque cada elemento que agregas a la lista también tendrá la función **GetTotem()**, otra cosa en vez de usar **this** puedes crear un objeto de tipo **Totem** y si vas a obtener múltiples registros crear un ciclo donde crees el objeto le asignes los valores y los guardes en la lista:

```
public List<Totem> GetTotem()
{
    List<Totem> lista = new List<Totem>();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnString))
        {
            string SQL = string.Empty;
            SQL += "SELECT id, dato1, dato2, dato3";
            SQL += " FROM";
            SQL += " mitabla";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "mitabla");
            conn.Close();
            this.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["suc"].ToString());
            this.Dato1= dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato1"].ToString();
            this.Dato2 = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato2"].ToString();
            this.Dato3 = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dato3"].ToString();
            lista.Add(this);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Mi Recomendación:

```
    public List<Totem> GetTotem()
    {
        List<Totem> lista = new List<Totem>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnString))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;
                SQL += "SELECT id, dato1, dato2, dato3";
                SQL += " FROM";
                SQL += " mitabla";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "mitabla");
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Totem objeto = new Totem();
                    objeto.Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["suc"].ToString());
                    objeto.Dato1 = row["dato1"].ToString();
                    objeto.Dato2 = row["dato2"].ToString();
                    objeto.Dato3 = row["dato3"].ToString();
                    lista.Add(objeto);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, finalmente lo hice con ciclo for